# How to set description for command, but not for option

Tags: java, jcommander

For every command I have a concrete class which implement certain interface.
For example:

```
public class FooCommand implements Command{

    @Parameter(names = {"-?","--help"}, description = "display this help",help = true)
    private boolean helpRequested = false;
    ...
}
```

And this is the usage message I get:

```
Usage: foo-command [options]
  Options:
    -?, --help
      display this help
```

How can I add description to command (but not to option). For example I want to get such usage message:

```
Usage: foo-command [options] - This command is used as base foo
  Options:
    -?, --help
      display this help
```

**EDIT** I have foo-command, boo-command, lala-command. However, all these commands are separate and are not within one main command (by other words this is not like git clone ...). 
This is the way I get usage

```
 JCommander jCommander=new JCommander(command, args);
 jCommander.setProgramName(commandName);//for example foo-command
 StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
 jCommander.usage(builder);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following snippet might be a starting point for what you are looking for.

```
@Parameters(commandDescription = "foo-command short description")
public class FooCommand implements Command {

    @Parameter(names = {"-?", "--help"}, description = "display this help", 
        help = true)
    private boolean helpRequested = false;

    @Parameter(description = "This command is used as base foo")
    public List<String> commandOptions;

    // your command code goes below
}
```

```
public class CommandMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JCommander jc = new JCommander();
        jc.setProgramName(CommandMain.class.getSimpleName());
        FooCommand foo = new FooCommand();
        jc.addCommand("foo-command", foo);
        // display the help
        jc.usage();
    }
}
```

output

```
Usage: CommandMain [options] [command] [command options]
  Commands:
    foo-command      foo-command short description
      Usage: foo-command [options] This command is used as base foo
        Options:
          -?, --help
             display this help
             Default: false
```

Also have a look at: [JCommander command syntax](http://jcommander.org/#_more_complex_syntaxes_commands)

**edit** Show the description for a command itself. The annotation `@Parameters(commandDescription = "foo-command short description")` on the class `FooCommand` can be omitted in that case.

```
Command command = new FooCommand();
JCommander jc = new JCommander(command, args);
jc.setProgramName("foo-command");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
jc.usage(builder);
System.out.println(builder);
```

output

```
Usage: foo-command [options] This command is used as base foo
  Options:
    -?, --help
       display this help
       Default: false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't need CommandMain. I have different commands without "Main"

Comment: @Pavel Command main is there to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe you should put in that case a better example of your code into your question.

Comment: @Pavel I added an amended code snippet. The classes are the same as before.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that `@Parameters(commandDescription = "")` can be omitted. So to get what I want is necessary to use `@Parameter(description = "This command is used as base foo")` - parameter without `names` for any field of class with any type. How can it be explained?

Comment: @Pavel I updated my answer to show where the `commandDescription` of the class is shown in the help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tested your solution - it works, but it is not `a clean` solution. So I opened an issue. See https://github.com/cbeust/jcommander/issues/352